# remove the extension from the key

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

How to remove the extension from the array key, ie .md.
It should look like this key: [about] => pages/about.md
Array:

Array:

```
(
    [_desktop.md] => pages/_desktop.md
    [about.md] => pages/about.md
    [contact.md] => pages/contact.md
    [errorpages] => Array
        (
            [403.md] => pages/errorpages/403.md
            [404.md] => pages/errorpages/404.md
            [500.md] => pages/errorpages/500.md
            [503.md] => pages/errorpages/503.md
        )

    [home.md] => pages/home.md
    [indexpage.md] => pages/indexpage.md
)
```

Code:

```
function generatePathTree($dir) {

    $pathstack = array($dir);
    $contentsroot = array();
    $contents = &$contentsroot;
    while ($path = array_pop($pathstack)) {
       $contents[basename($path)] = array();
       $contents = &$contents[basename($path)];
       foreach (scandir($path) as $filename) {
           if ('.' != substr($filename, 0, 1)) {
               $newPath = $path.'/'.$filename;
               if (is_dir($newPath)) {
                   array_push($pathstack, $newPath);
                   $contents[basename($newPath)] = array();
               } else {
                   $contents[basename($filename)] = $newPath;
               }
           }
           $contentsroot = preg_replace("/\\.[^.]*$/", "", basename($filename));
       }
    }
    return $contentsroot[basename($dir)];
}
```

I tried so:

```
$contentsroot = preg_replace("/\\.[^.]*$/", "", basename($filename));
```

But alas.

How to do?

Comment: Updated my code, your regexp is a little bit off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code block (This is where filename gets assigned instead of dir):

```
else {
      $fileExtRemoved = preg_replace("/[\.](.*)/", "", $filename);
      $contents[basename($fileExtRemoved)] = $newPath;
}
```

Your regexp is a little bit off, this is the correct one:
https://3v4l.org/mMPrt

Answer (score 0):

You can assigne the old value to new key and then unset the old key

```
   $arr['about'] = $arr['about.md'];
    unset($arr['about.md']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's three characters on all of them?
So why not just use `sub_str($key , 0, -3);`?

If it's always three chars it should work, and as I see it, it seems to be three.

So maybe:

```
 $contents[basename(substr($filename,0,-3))];
```

Answer (score 0):

Requirement: remove any part of the array key string after the first `.` if it exists in the string.

Solution:

```
list($key,) = explode('.', $old_key);
$arr[$key] = $arr[$old_key];
unset($arr[$old_key]);
```

A side note: there must be a better way to do the recursive loop. But a quick look suggests that `array_walk_recursive` only operates on the leaf nodes; `array_map` and `array_reduce` don't have recursive variants and they only take values anyway. Since you didn't explicitly ask for this, I'll stop there.